# MATLAB anonymous function detailed workings

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

I noticed anonymous functions in MATLAB can be used without specifying all the needed variables within - however, these don't seem updated at 'runtime' (if I use that term correctly):

```
a=1;
myfx = @(t) a+t; % a is 1 at this point, the function simply adds 't' to a
a=2;
myfx(1) % a in the base workspace is now 2, yet the function seemingly computes 1+1

ans =

     2
```

Can someone explain what goes on '*under the hood*' (i.e. MATLAB-internally) here? It seems unintuitive to me and I imagine this may cause some common pitfalls, that should be taken into consideration.

Comment: Not asking for extreme detail here, just to get a better intuition of how to think about it

Comment: Short answer is that everything (except handle objects) is passed by value.

Comment: The variable inside a function handle (like `myfx`) are persistent, they are stored inside the function handle, so you can even clear all the external variable and `myfx(1)` will still output `2`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force evaluation of variables in MATLAB anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808668/force-evaluation-of-variables-in-matlab-anonymous-function). Not an exact dupe, but I think it answers your question (i.e. that it's a closure).

Comment: @AndrasDeak I wish I had more explanations about e.g. how the memory is handled (e.g. if you use a large struct, is it just copied into memory and left there as-is?) but the answers there provide plenty of information, thank you

Comment: Looking at system RAM usage after each of the following commands, `a.a = rand(10000); f = @(t) a.a*t; a.a = rand(10000);` it looks like a copy of the data is made only when `a.a` is updated.

Comment: thank you (everyone) for all the kind answers and patience. Follow up question: I'm assuming there is no sensible way to modify the variables within a defined anonymous function, right?

Comment: You should make them input arguments to your function. Or write a regular function with global variables (not recommended) or create a custom class where these variables are properties of the class.

Comment: Only objects of [handle classes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/handle-classes.html) can be modified. But in general MATLAB objects have value semantics.